# Any way to avoid restarting httpd to apply a user's php.ini file?

Tags: php, apache, configuration-files

I have a shared hosting server hosting lots of different accounts (domains).
Server is standard LAMP stack using webmin/virtualmin to administer/create accounts.

Each domain has its own /home/[account]/etc/php.ini file.  This allows settings to be adjusted for each account individually.  For example, Display_Errors can be set in this file.

However, if any changes are made to the php.ini file for a specific account, the whole httpd process must be restarted, affecting ALL hosted accounts, in order to apply the settings.  End users don't have permissions to do this, obviously, so I have to do it for them.  Is there any way to apply individual php.ini files to that particular domain without needing to restart the httpd process?

Note: end users don't have SSH access.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
service apache2 reload
```

instead of

```
service apache2 restart
```

Substitute `apache2` for `httpd` or whatever your specific system's configuration entails. `service` is usually an Ubuntu thing; other systems invoke services in different ways. The key terms here are `restart` vs. `reload`.

---

If you are *not* using `libapache2-mod-php`, and are instead using `ProxyPass` or PHP FPM, substitute the above with

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

---

Since end-users don't have SSH access, you'll either need to build some sort of interface for them to reload the server, or reload the configuration upon modification or with an interval.

This is generally achieved using a [CRON job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml).

Comment: Yes, but since end-users don't have SSH access, how could they do it?

Comment: It's just annoying that they can easily change their php.ini file, but can't apply the changes without asking me.  Sort of defeats the purpose, don't you think?

Comment: @RyanGriggs Nope, it doesn't. Changing the PHP.ini is considered a "safe" thing; restarting services is not. Reloading PHP configuration adds a considerable amount of startup time, so re-loading it on every page view would be a performance hit.

Comment: Depending on how you allow them to change the php.ini file, you could detect these changes and reload the server upon modification of their php.ini file.

Comment: Also, users can't issue a httpd reload due to permissions, even if they did have SSH access, right?  Just tried this with a non-root user, and got "not reloading due to configuration syntax error".  But works fine as "root".

Comment: @RyanGriggs you could write a CRON Job to reload every hour

Comment: @Qix Yes I understand it would be a performance hit to reload the config every time a page loads, but it doesn't make sense that an end-user can change his ini file but has now way to *apply* those changes.

Comment: Correct; like I said, you'd have to build some sort of mechanism that would safely reload the server as root (or preferably whatever the server is running as; usually `www-data`).

Comment: @RyanGriggs It makes complete sense. PHP.ini wasn't meant to be changed constantly.

Comment: @cmorissey - That makes the most sense.  A cron job would do the trick, and users wouldn't have to bother me.  However, how would the 'reload' process affect active sites?  Would all sites go offline for the split second the config is reloading?

Comment: @RyanGriggs Nope. `reload` reloads all configuration. `restart` does a true die-reload cycle.

Comment: OK I understand.  Sounds like a cron job is the best way then.  @comrissey - put that in an answer and I'll credit you.  Thanks

Comment: @RyanGriggs I just updated my answer to include it.

Comment: @Qix, thanks, but didn't cmorissey suggest the cron job first? shouldn't he get credit for the answer, as that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @RyanGriggs It would be a duplicate. Check out the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on answering questions :)